# ggtree setting height scale

Tags: r, scale, ggtree

I'm doing microssatellite analysis to understand genetic relationship between fungal isolates. For that I first calculated the Jaccard’s coefficient and then want to generate a dendrogram using UPGMA cluster analysis.

I did the following:

## Distance matrix computation

```
jacc_coef <- vegdist(HC_df, method = "jaccard") *100
```

(HC_df is my data frame)

## Hierarchical clustering

```
afu_clin.hc <- hclust(d = jacc_coef, method = "average")
```

When I plot `afu_clin.hc` with another package I obtain the heigth scale corresponding to the % of dissimilarity that was calculated before.

```
HC <- fviz_dend(x = afu_clin.hc, cex = 0.7, lwd = 0.7, horiz = TRUE) 
print(HC)
```

I obtain the following plot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4sNv.png)

However, when I try to use the ggtree the scale is different. I'm wondering how can I use ggtree to display my dendrogram with the height scale as % dissimilarity calculated with Jaccard’s coefficient.
I used this code:

```
hc_tree <- ggtree(afu_clin.hc, size =0.8) + geom_tiplab(angle = 90, hjust=1, offset=-.05) + layout_dendrogram() + theme_dendrogram()
```

obtained this plot (I don't understand this scale, where does it come from?)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6cB0.png)

How can I use ggtree to plot a similar dendrogram to the one that I showed first?
Thank you,

Best
Daryna